# An item with the same key has already been added in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Why I am getting the error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

In ssrs for code:

```
SELECT    e.id                              AS eid, 
          p.dscr                            AS jdscr, 
          e.startdate                       AS hdate, 
          Concat(e.fname,e.lname)           AS NAME, 
          m.weekenddate                     AS weekenddate
          m.bramt                           AS bramt, 
          m.conamt                          AS conamt, 
          w.twork                           AS twork 
FROM      tblemp e 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                   SELECT   cid, 
                            weekenddate, 
                            COALESCE(( 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN mrtype = 'BR' THEN sum(mgamt) 
                            END),0) AS bramt , 
                            COALESCE(( 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN mrtype = 'con' THEN sum(mgamt) 
                            END),0) AS conamt 
                   FROM     mngrtbl 
                   GROUP BY cid, 
                            weekendate, 
                            mrtype) m  ON e.id = m.cid 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                   SELECT   emp, 
                            sum(twork) AS twork 
                   FROM     tblans 
                   GROUP BY emp) w  ON e.id = w.emp 
LEFT JOIN pname p ON e.pid = p.ponid
```

Comment: This is running fine in sql server .Any help greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a command after Weekenddate in 
    `m.weekenddate as weekenddate m.bramt as bramt`

can you format the question with a code block please?

Comment: could you please format youre code so it is readable a little bit better?

Comment: select e.id as EID,p.Dscr as JDscr,e.startdate as Hdate,concat(e.fname,e.lname) as name,m.weekenddate as weekenddate m.bramt as bramt,m.conamt as conamt,w.twork as twork from tblemp e left join (select cid,weekenddate,coalesce((case when mrtype = 'BR' then sum(mgamt) end),0) as bramt , coalesce((case when mrtype = 'con' then sum(mgamt) end),0) as conamt from mngrtbl group by Cid,weekendate,mrtype)m on e.id = m.cid left join (select emp,sum(twork) as twork from tblans group by emp)w on e.id = w.emp left join pname p on e.pid = p.ponid

Comment: I am not very experienced but when I got this error it was because I had the same field twice in my report without renaming it.  It ran fine in the SQL query pane but not in the report builder.